# На каком языке писать комментарии в пет проекте Python

Tags: python, code-style, комментарии

Хочу устроиться Python разработчиком, в своем резюме на джуна указываю ссылку на свой гитхаб.
Подскажите, на каком языке лучше писать комментарии к коду в пет проекте Python, на русском или на английском? Или лучше и так и так? Резюме буду отправлять в русскоязычные компании.

Answer (score 1):

Сам код должен быть на английском. Мало где будут рады увидеть функции или классы на русском.

А вот что касается комментариев, то тут спорно. В международных компаниях хотели бы увидеть на английском. А вот в некоторых российских комментарии пишутся только на русском. Возможно, стоит заранее поинтересоваться у работающих в тех компаниях, куда собираешься подавать резюме.

И ещё момент. Есть мнение, что комментариев  в коде желательно вообще избегать - код должен быть понятным сам по себе.

Если же речь идёт о документации в духе jsdoc (для питона нагуглил [такое](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/automatic-doc-generation.html)), то я бы предпочёл на английском как и код (если нет явного требования писать на русском).

Comment: Про код понятно, уже переименовал все переменные, которые для себя называл транслитом, ну когда оставлю комментарии на 2 языках на всякий случай. А насчет кода без комментариев, я пока до этого не дорос, даже сейчас открыл код, который писал полгода назад и если б не комментарии, не понял бы некоторые части. Ну будем стремиться =). Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @Юрий, на мой взгляд, на двух языках - это странно.

Comment: Я может чего не догоняю, а кто мешает (при наличии уже написанных комментариях на 2х языках) сделать дубликат проекта и в одном оставить русские комментарии, а в другом английские? И оставлять 2 ссылки типа `project with en comments` и `проект с комментариями на русском языке`. Сие может быть оценено будущим работодателем

Comment: @Namerek, вероятно то, что обычно проекты подразумевают что-то полезное, а не просто "я вот тут для резюме сделал и забросил". Синхронизировать 2 репозитория просто ради комментов на разных языках - попахивает каким-то идиотизмом.